# Reference SlideView in XAML.Windows Phone Programming

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

Hello I have an error on my windows phone project. I am trying to create a lateral menu using SlideView Library, but my project can't find it.

MainPage.xaml

```
<Page
x:Class="AppBlankProject.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:AppBlankProject"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:slideview="clr-namespace:SlideView.Library;assembly=SlideView.Library"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
        <TransitionCollection>
            <EntranceThemeTransition/>
        </TransitionCollection>
    </Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!-- Title Panel -->
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0"
                Margin="0,0,0,470" 
                Grid.RowSpan="2"
                Background="#FE8A01">
        <Image
            Source="Assets/logo.png" 
            Stretch="None" 
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            >
            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1"/>
            </Image.RenderTransform>
        </Image>
    </StackPanel>
    <Grid Background="LightGray">
        <slideview:SlideView x:Name="sld_view">
            <Grid x:Name="PainelMenu" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="400">
                <!-- Composição do menu -->
                </Grid>
                <Grid x:Name="PainelPrincipal" Width="480">
                    <!-- Composição da página -->
                </Grid>
        </slideview:SlideView>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

So, I am getting this error:

```
Error   1   Unknown type 'SlideView' in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:SlideView.Library;assembly=SlideView.Library'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is SlideView? What is this library you are using? Is the SlideView control in the SlideView.Library namespace? Or is it a namespace like SlideView.Library.Controls or SlideView.Controls or something differnent?

Comment: it is supposed to be a library to help with Lateral Menus. It is just slideView.

Comment: I'm asking what is the fully qualified namespace? the error is stating that 'SlideViiew' does not exist in that namespace

Answer (score 0):

The solution I've found was this:

I changed this line :

```
xmlns:slideview="clr-namespace:SlideView.Library;assembly=SlideView.Library"
```

to this:

```
xmlns:slideview="using : SlideView.Library"
```